# Is there a way to get a list of IDs that are currently pinned on a website using Selenium?

Tags: html, jquery, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a webscraper that needs to open up multiple tabs of items whose icons are filled. For example each page I need to open has div class="course-selector-item-pinned" in it's source code.

```
<dropdown-content max-width="800" min-width="450" no-padding="" vertical-offset="0" dir="ltr" dropdown-content="" style="--dropdown-verticaloffset:0px;" opened=""><div class="classselector-wrapper" aria-live="assertive">
    <div id="classSelectorId" class="placeholder placeholder-live" aria-live="assertive">
        <div class="2_7_615 2_8_459 body-compact">
            <ul class="datalist vui-list">
                <li class="datalist-item datalist-item-actionable datalist-simpleitem vui-selected" id="2_9_421" data-actionid="2_11_656">
                    <div class="datalist-item-content" title="Class 1">
                        <div class="class-selector-item class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id="12345">
                            <div class="2_160_610 class-selector-item-name">
                                <a class="link datalist-item-actioncontrol" id="2_11_656" href="/abc/home/12345">Class1</a>
                            </div>
                            <span id="2_10_630" data-active-id="2_161_292" data-inactive-id="2_162_883"><button-icon icon="tier1:pin-filled" id="2_161_292" onclick="O(&quot;__g2&quot;,3)();" text="Un-pin &quot;Class 1&quot;" dir="ltr" type="button"></button-icon>
                            <button-icon icon="tier1:pin-hollow" class="hidden" id="2_162_883" onclick="O(&quot;__g2&quot;,4)();" text="Pin &quot;Class 1&quot;" dir="ltr" type="button"></button-icon>
                            </span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="datalist-item datalist-item-actionable datalist-simpleitem vui-selected" id="2_12_929" data-actionid="2_14_114">
                    <div class="datalist-item-content" title="Class 2">
                        <div class="class-selector-item class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id="23456">
                            <div class="2_160_610 class-selector-item-name">
                                <a class="link datalist-item-actioncontrol" id="2_14_114" href="/abc/home/23456">Class 2</a>
                            </div>
                            <span id="2_13_229" data-active-id="2_163_477" data-inactive-id="2_164_80"><button-icon icon="tier1:pin-filled" id="2_163_477" onclick="O(&quot;__g2&quot;,5)();" text="Un-pin &quot;Class 2&quot;" dir="ltr" type="button"></button-icon>
                            <button-icon icon="tier1:pin-hollow" class="hidden" id="2_164_80" onclick="O(&quot;__g2&quot;,6)();" text="Pin &quot;Class 2&quot;" dir="ltr" type="button"></button-icon>
                            </span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="datalist-item datalist-item-actionable datalist-simpleitem vui-selected" id="2_15_372" data-actionid="2_17_26">
                    <div class="datalist-item-content" title="Class 3">
                        <div class="class-selector-item class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id="34567">
                            <div class="2_160_610 class-selector-item-name">
                                <a class="link datalist-item-actioncontrol" id="2_17_26" href="/abc/home/34567">Class 3</a>
                            </div>
                            <span id="2_16_595" data-active-id="2_165_349" data-inactive-id="2_166_873"><button-icon icon="tier1:pin-filled" id="2_165_349" onclick="O(&quot;__g2&quot;,7)();" text="Un-pin &quot;Class 3&quot;" dir="ltr" type="button"></button-icon>
                            <button-icon icon="tier1:pin-hollow" class="hidden" id="2_166_873" onclick="O(&quot;__g2&quot;,8)();" text="Pin &quot;Class 3&quot;" dir="ltr" type="button"></button-icon>
                            </span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
```

I need the webscraper to find all div classes that has "course-selector-item-pinned" and then take the value in data-org-unit-ids. For example the list would return [12345, 23456, 34567] in this case.

The line of source code I am referring to is:

```
<div class="class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id"12345">
<div class="class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id"23456">
<div class="class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id"34567">
```

This is what I have done so far the list is not returning anything.

## Get List of Unit IDs

```
courseString='https://example.com/abc/p/home'
listofUnitID =[]
links = [elem.get_attribute("data-org-unit-id") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class-selector-item-pinned")]
```

## Filter out none type from list

```
res = []
for val in links: 
    if val != None : 
        res.append(val) 
print(res)
```

## List to Keep Only Classes

```
for i in res:
    if courseString in i:
        listOfHref.append(i)
        print(listOfUnitID)
```

Comment: what does the `links` array contain? does it show any elements?

Answer (score 1):

If I looks your HTML, actually you want scrape the following `div`:

```
<div class="class-selector-item class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id="34567">
...
...
```

Not this:

```
<div class="class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id"12345">
<div class="class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id"23456">
<div class="class-selector-item-pinned" data-org-unit-id"34567">
```

It causes you code not returning anything, because you are targeting the div with multiple classes.

`.find_elements_by_class_name` just for single class name.

You can try with `.find_elements_by_css_selector('css_selector')`, like this:

```
links = [elem.get_attribute("data-org-unit-id") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".class-selector-item.class-selector-item-pinned")]
```